# What's the meaning of "portion" in the phrase "big portion"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am looking for restaurants that offer huge dishes. I found a phrase that says "Best places for big portions". In this sentence, does the "portion" just mean food? Or the space, or something else?

Comment: Nakamura-san, welcome to the site!

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question was voted down?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Tom. If you'll take a few minutes review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages, you'll understand our mission and policies. (This question is can be answered by consulting a dictionary.)

Answer (score 1):

> **Portion** *noun*
>   1.2 An amount of food suitable for or served to one person.
>   *‘burger joints offering huge portions’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/portion)

Consider going to a restaurant and placing an order. When your order arrives, there is a piece of beef, a couple of potatoes, and some greens (vegetables). In the rest of this example, I've linked to web pages that use the highlighted phrases. Click on each site and search the page for the relevant phrase (e.g. "portion of steak").

You could say you received a [portion of steak](http://www.bodyandsoul.com.au/diet/lose-weight/are-you-eating-healthy-portion-sizesr/news-story/4820293d3e2bec5b4bdb1e15c0545587), a [portion of potatoes](http://theconversation.com/potatoes-deserve-to-be-a-part-of-the-super-food-family-59625), and a [portion of greens](https://breakingmuscle.com/nutrition/7-simple-ways-to-get-more-greens-in-your-diet).

You can also refer to the order as a whole as the [portion you were served](http://en.amerikanki.com/tips-dealing-young-picky-eaters/).

You ask:

> I am looking for restaurants that offer huge dishes. I found a phrase that says "Best places for big portions". In this sentence, does the "portion" just mean food? Or the space, or something else?

The phrase *big portions* uses this last form, and indicates that the amount served per order is large. It refers only to the food, not the plate, the space, or anything else.

Comment: "Serve" in first and last sentences should be "serving." // So if you ordered chicken, green beans and carrots, then you'd get a large portion of chicken, a large portion of green beans and a large portion of carrots. So "portions" is referring to the individual food items ordered, not the whole order as one thing.

Comment: @MaxW Although the dictionaries define *serve* and *serving* the way you indicate, my use of *serve* is also idiomatic in contemporary usage. [Here's an example.](http://www.mydailyintake.net/for-food-manufacturers/) Changing it the way you suggest also makes my first sentence ambiguous (*cf* 'serving' as gerund). Also, can you please indicate where my answer suggested that "portion" refers to "the whole order"? (That request is *not* rhetorical.) I specifically used the term "menu *item*" to avoid that impression.

Comment: I wasn't sure if a non-native speaker would understand the "menu item" properly so i tried to give an explicit example instead of inferring the notion. A menu item is also a bit ambiguous.  Sometimes you can order a meat entree for example for one price and and vegetables would be ordered as separate items with their own price. Other times the meat entree might have a price which includes a choice of two vegetables from a list. On yet other menus the meat and side dishes are a single item on the menu. So a steak might be listed with a salad and a baked potato as one menu "item."

Comment: @MaxW Thanks for your comments. I've rewritten my answer using your idea of explicitly listing the various items on the plate. You may be right about AuE vs AmE. I've avoided the term *serve* and *serving* altogether in the latest version.